# How to switch Windows Xbox Game Bar between primary and secondary screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I am so glad I found game bar but it has one huge disadvantage. I have a laptop with a secondary screen connected and it doesn't have an option to switch screens.

It only opens us of my secondary screen, not my primary screen.
It doesn't support dragging the window.

[Multiple screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWRnk.png)

[Extended display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArrJT.png)

I went into the settings and there are no way to select the screen I wish to use. I wish to use my primary screen the laptop screen to record but if I select Game Bar from either Screen's taskbar it always opens up on my secondary screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround. I think it is a bug limited to the Taskbar and Xbox Gamebar.

Gamebar doesn't support switching between screens so you have to close and open it.

However the problem is clicking on the taskbar Start button, search or select gamebar doesn't open gamebar on the screen you have entered the search or selected the program. This is a bug.

The workaround for this bug:
Gamebar must not be open or visible on your screen. If it is then close it.

1. Decide which screen you wish to open XBox Gamebar.
   On that screen right click on a blank part of that screen's taskbar and select taskbar settings. This opens the setting window. Close that settings window.
2. This time on the same screen taskbar when you select Game Bar from the start button or search for it from the start Start button by typing "Game" or clicking the filtered icons it will open XBox Game bar on that screen.

Comment: This answer does not make sense.  Could you clarify it? I have tried opening the Settings application on the secondary monitor. Xbox GameBar seems to prefer the Primary screen.

Comment: Both screens have tasks bars.

Comment: Yes;  That is the default configuration for a 2 monitor setup running Windows 10.  The steps are not clear

Comment: Selecting the program from the taskbar screen you want to work on doesn't work always. You basically have to right before you do it right click on the taskbar and select settings. Close the window. This will trick Windows into thinking that is the active taskbar to open Xbox Game bar when you select it

Comment: Close Settings before you close Game Bar?  I tried your solution at least 10 times (it didn’t work)

Comment: That order is wrong. Game bar has to be closed or miminized before you want to open it.

Comment: The first step in your answer body is to open and the close the Settings application on the monitor you want Game Bar to appear on.  The second step is to launch Game Bar from the Start Menu on that same monitor.  I have done that and regardless of which monitor Settings is closed on Game Bar opens on the same monitor every time

Comment: Worked like magic. Windows 10 pro.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me either. I managed to open the Xbox overlay on the second screen (I had to open the taskbar settings and drag them to the second screen and without closing them press Win+G). If I run recording without closing settings, I get error 2147942487. If I close taskbar settings, the Xbox overlay is shown on the fist screen.

Comment: In my case it seems the first set is not needed. If I click the Start menu, search "Game" and click on "XBox Game bar" it always open it on the screen I have clicked the start menu on... what is annoying is that if I type Windows+G to open the settings it opens them on a secondary monitor moving the widgets... basically "windows+G" is unusable if you want to show this stuff on the primary monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different workaround, I selected the external monitor and made this my main display and then I opened Gamebar. You can do that in Settings -> Display -> select the display where you want to record and select "Make this my Main Display"

Answer (score 0):

What has been said by @choba78 isn't totally wrong, but isn't right either.

So you have to open any app in the second monitor (if it opens in the first one you just have to drag it to the second, it won't change anything) and then (without closing it) press **Win + G**.

Answer (score -1):

The solution here didn't work for me.

But I came across a quick workaround to drag the screen, [Alt + Enter] shows the window so you can drag it, then [Alt + Enter] again to remove back to full screen.

Comment: Which of the 7 solutions didn’t work? There is little to no difference between the steps you describe and the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

Wow, I just stubble upon it, when I was messing with Win+G.
Click on an application that is on the monitor you want, then press Win+G.
If your discord is on my right monitor. Just go into the application, like your looking at a messages, then press Win+G.

Answer (score -1):

so I found the solution. You go to the display settings and there should be two squares representing your two monitors. Click on the monitor you want the game to show up on and then below that it says “make this my main display” and click that and you should be good to go. If you want it reversed then just do the same thing but with the other monitor. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

The issue you will find is if you are using message chat and you have it open in another monitor the moment you click on it to type a response it wil go to what ever screen you have the last application open and using. so not really a perma fix. i wish you could set it to open in a certain display seeing i use 4 monitors to stream and its annoying when i click on it to reply to a message and it takes over my most recent screen messing up the gaming or display capture used in OBS